# Don't understand the error in appending a new item to a Linked List (At Beginning and End)

Tags: c, linked-list, singly-linked-list

As mentioned I don't seem to be able to understand the error in my code, what is it that I'm doing wrong in this particular piece of code:

The Node is written as such:

```
struct Node {
    int data;
    struct Node *link;
};
```

This is the append to the beginning:

```
void Shift(struct Node **head, int new_data) {
    struct Node *New;
    
    New = (struct Node *)malloc(sizeof(struct Node));
    if (New == NULL) {
        printf("It is Null\n");
    }
    New->data = new_data;
    New->link = head;
}
```

This is the append to the end:

```
void Shift(struct Node *head, int new_data) {
    
    while (head !=  NULL) {
        head = head->link;
    }
    struct Node *New;
    New = (struct Node *)malloc(sizeof(struct Node));
    if (New == NULL) {
        printf("It is Null\n");
    }
    New->link = NULL;
    New->data = new_data;
```

If anyone knows what's up, please tell me what to add and why. Thanks in advance!!

I've looked it up and it said that I had to do `head->link = new`, but it results in a never ending cascade of number...

Comment: If head is the begining of the list, then it will need to be changed to point to the first element after appending to the begining of the list.

Answer (score 1):

There are multiple problems:

- you do not return if memory allocation fails.
- the first version (inserting at the beginning of the list) does not handle `head` properly: it is a pointer to the head node pointer of the list so `New->link` must be set to `*head` and `*head` must be updated to become the new head: `*head = New;`.
- the second version skips the nodes until `head` is a null pointer, causing undefined behavior if you link the new node as its `next` node. You should instead loop until you have the *last* node of the list and link the `New` node as its `next` node.
- the second version should also take a double pointer `struct Node **head` so the head of the list can be updated if the list was empty.

Here are modified versions:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

struct Node {
    int data;
    struct Node *link;
};

void Shift(struct Node **head, int new_data) {
    struct Node *New = malloc(sizeof(struct Node));
    if (New == NULL) {
        printf("Shift: Memory allocation error\n");
        return;
    }
    New->data = new_data;
    New->link = *head;
    *head = New;
}

void Append(struct Node **head, int new_data) {
    struct Node *New = malloc(sizeof(struct Node));
    if (New == NULL) {
        printf("Append: Memory allocation error\n");
        return;
    }
    New->data = new_data;
    New->next = NULL;
    if (*head) {
        struct Node *last = *head;
        while (last->next)
            last = last->next;
        last->next = New;
    } else {
        *head = New;
    }
}
```

The `Append` function can be simplified into this more compact version that may be more difficult to understand:

```
void Append(struct Node **head, int new_data) {
    struct Node *New = malloc(sizeof(struct Node));
    if (New == NULL) {
        printf("Append: Memory allocation error\n");
        return;
    }
    New->data = new_data;
    New->next = NULL;
    while (*head) {
        head = &(*head)->next;
    }
    *head = New;
}
```